# How to save EditText value in Shared Preferences when user swipe fragment in viewpager?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-sharedpreferences

I have multiple fragment in viewpager and each fragment have almost ten editext so I want to save all value in shared preference. when user swipe fragment one then data of fragment1 will saved in shared preference and same for all fragment.

```
public void user(String EditText1, String EditText2){

        // Storing data in pref
        editor.putString(value1, EditText1);
        editor.putString(value2, EditText2);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Below is my code to get edittext value to save in shared preference -

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(9);

        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
                EditText1= f1.txtEditText1.getText().toString();
                EditText2= f1.txtEditText2.getText().toString();

                session.user(EditText1, EditText1);

            }
        });
```

When I fill all edit text on first fragment and when I swipe i am getting below error -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor `android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor.putString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `editor` is null inside constructor of User class. That's why you are getting crash.

Also `onPageScrollStateChanged` - is bad place for doing thing like that, because it will be called many times during one fragment swipping. Better to use `onPageScrolled`.

Also there is no sense to create fragment in order to save something, you need to use fragment's instance that was visible for user. [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager) how to get fragment by position.

Comment: Thanks Divers. Not i am getting value from session like below -

// get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user= session.getUserData();
        // user id
        final String abc = user.get(SessionManager.EditText1);

Now I am set abc in editText1 - 

EditText1.setText(abc);


Its giving me error  -

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference